# PHP mailer - double emails (Joomla module)

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I have php form (Joomla module) that submits emails and saves user emails to database.
Form is checking if user email already exists in database, if not email is saved (new joomla user is created) and mail is submitted to admin email and user email. This part works fine. 
But if email is already in database (returning user scenario) form sends double emails to both administrator and user.

```
 $mailer = & JFactory::getMailer();

        $mailer->isHTML();
        $mailer->setSender($params->get('email_from'));
        $mailer->addRecipient($params->get('email_to'));
        $mailer->addBCC($email);
        $mailer->setSubject($params->get('subject'));
        $mailer->setBody($message); 

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = 'SELECT id FROM #__users WHERE email = ' . $db->Quote($email);
$db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);
$check = $db->loadResult();

if(!$check){

    $udate = date('d/m/Y');
    $utime= date("h:i:s");
    $udata = array( 
    "name"=>"user".$udate."-".$utime,
    "username"=>"user".$utime,
    "password"=>$utime,
    "password2"=>$utime,
    "email"=>$email,
    "block"=>0,
    "groups"=>array("9")
);
$user = clone(JFactory::getUser());

if(!$user->bind($udata)) {
    throw new Exception("Could not bind data. Error: " . $user->getError());
}
if (!$user->save()) {
     throw new Exception("Could not save user. Error: " . $user->getError());
}
   return $user->id;         

 JFactory::getSession()->clear('user');


    }   

    $send = & $mailer->Send();
    $mailer->ClearAddresses();
    $mailer->ClearAllRecipients();
        if($send = true){
            echo "Mail sent";
            return true;
            }
        else if ($send != true)
        {
            echo "Error sending email: ". $send->message;
            return false;

            }

        }
```

Comment: I have also tried this but no results  $send= & $mailer->Send();
  if(!$send){
   echo "Error sending email: ". $send->message;
   return false;
   }
  
  else{
  
  $mailer->ClearAllRecipients();
  $mailer->ClearAddresses();
  $mailer->ClearBCCs();
  unset($mailer);
         echo "Mail sent";
   return true;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some obvious errors in your code. The line:

```
JFactory::getSession()->clear('user');
```

is never reached, as the script is returning before this line. Also, the line:

```
if($send = true){
```

simply assigns true to send and will always be true.

I also question this line:

```
$send = & $mailer->Send();
```

You are here assigning a reference to $send for some reason. Dont.

I'm not sure why you get the errors you observe, but: I would really consider properly formatting your code with correct indents, it makes it much easier to spot errors. And try to clean out other errors... Consider that your function might be called twice for some reason...

Comment: thanks for answering my question :) by the time i got back to stackoverflow i have already spotted and corrected issues you pointed out. the last thing you said in your answer made me stop and think, I looked into server log and found that it was called twice, problem was caused by module position duplicate loading :D